# Whether ubuntu touch run on any device that running android previously?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I came across some youtube videos that they mentioned ubuntu touch can be installed in any device that supports android. is it true? then why it is mentioned separately that only nexus or some bq acquaris can only run ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not true. According to Ubuntu, only a few devices are supported. These devices are officially supported and still get updates from Ubuntu. Development editions? Some tablets. Including mine (TF300T) Still, it's a mix of unofficial and official. The rest of the devices are completely unsupported. Seriously. Devices like the TF101T (the tablet i had before TF300T) are not supported. Yet.